# JavaScript function that calculates how many year, month and days between two dates

Tags: javascript

I am looking to calculate the age in years, months and days using JavaScript. This code works for some dates, however it doesn't work if the date is less than 1 year away or anytime in the past at all.

```
function age(year, month, day) {

var today = new Date();
var endDate = new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
var dayDiff = Math.floor((endDate - today) / 86400000);


if (dayDiff >= 365) {
    var year = Math.floor(dayDiff / 365);
    var remainder = Math.floor(dayDiff) - (year * 365);
    var months = Math.floor(remainder / 30);
}

var days = Math.floor(remainder) - (months * 30);

return year + " years" + " " + months + " months" + " " + days + "        days";
}
 console.log(age(2017, 11, 17));
 console.log(age(2015, 3, 6));
```

Answer (score 0):

> however it doesn't work if the date is less than 1 year away or anytime in the past at all.

Look at the conditional of your code:

```
if (dayDiff >= 365) {
    ...
}
```

That would explain why it's not triggering when the date is less than 1 year (365 days) away.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this function to get the "natural" number of years, months and days between two dates:

```js
function interval(date1, date2) {
    if (date1 > date2) { // swap
        var result = interval(date2, date1);
        result.years  = -result.years;
        result.months = -result.months;
        result.days   = -result.days;
        return result;
    }
    result = {
        years:  date2.getYear()  - date1.getYear(),
        months: date2.getMonth() - date1.getMonth(),
        days:   date2.getDate()  - date1.getDate()
    };
    if (result.days < 0) {
        result.months--;
        // days = days left in date1's month, 
        //   plus days that have passed in date2's month
        var copy1 = new Date(date1.getTime());
        copy1.setDate(32);
        result.days = 32-date1.getDate()-copy1.getDate()+date2.getDate();
    }
    if (result.months < 0) {
        result.years--;
        result.months+=12;
    }
    return result;
}

// Be aware that the month argument is zero-based (January = 0)
var date1 = new Date(2015, 4-1, 6);
var date2 = new Date(2015, 5-1, 9);

document.write(JSON.stringify(interval(date1, date2)));
```

This solution will treat leap years (29 February) and month length differences in a way we would naturally do (I think).

So for example, the interval between 28 February 2015 and 28 March 2015 will be considered exactly one month, not 28 days. If both those days are in 2016, the difference will still be exactly one month, not 29 days.

Dates with exactly the same month and day, but different year, will always have a difference of an exact number of years. So the difference between 2015-03-01 and 2016-03-01 will be exactly 1 year, not 1 year and 1 day (because of counting 365 days as 1 year).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options : either strip the `if (dayDiff >= 365)` condition altogether or write an `else` statement to your `if` to handle cases where `dayDiff < 365`.

Following your logic:

```js
function age(year, month, day) {

  var today = new Date();
  var endDate = new Date(year, month, day).getTime();
  var dayDiff = Math.floor((endDate - today) / 86400000);


  if (dayDiff >= 365) {
    var year = Math.floor(dayDiff / 365);
    var remainder = Math.floor(dayDiff) - (year * 365);
    var months = Math.floor(remainder / 30);
  } else {
    var year = 0;
    var remainder = Math.floor(dayDiff) - (year * 365);
    var months = Math.floor(remainder / 30);
  }

  var days = Math.floor(remainder) - (months * 30);

  return year + " years" + " " + months + " months" + " " + days + "        days";
}

document.write("<p>" + age(2017, 11, 17) + "</p>");
document.write("<p>" + age(2016, 7, 11) + "</p>");
```

Comment: So which solution did you choose ? :)